# styled title keep pushing thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on bootstrap blog style.. so I have three thumbnails in every row.
thumbnail contain image, h3 text and p text (description)

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="xxx" alt="xxx">
<div class="caption">
<p class="text-muted"> <i style="font-size:1.2em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </i> xxx <i style="font-size:1.2em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> xxx</p>
<h3><a title="xxx" href="http://localhost/blog/Article.php?id=xxx">xxx</a></h3>
<p>xxx</p>
<a href="http://localhost/blog/Article.php?id=xxx" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">إقرأ المزيد →</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm disabled">شاهده xxx</a>
</div>
</div>
```

xxx is php code

and my title css code of

```
<h3><a title="xxx" href="http://localhost/blog/Article.php?id=xxx">xxx</a></h3>
```

is

```
    a:hover {
    position: relative;
}

a[title]:hover:after {
    content: attr(title);
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

so without hovering the link(before):

[image: http://www8.0zz0.com/2015/06/26/02/852135296.png]

and after hover the h3 title, the gray box showed successfully but it pushed the bottom thumbnails... i try to fix that with position:absolute to thumbnail but doesnt work(after):

[image: http://www11.0zz0.com/2015/06/26/02/599780954.png]

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help if you'd provide a live example of this issue (e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is `:after` should have `position: absolute` that throws it out of element stack.

Comment: thank you for answer but its not working -> the gray box is behind thumbnails

Comment: Also set `z-index: 1` to `:after` to put it over `a` element.
Edit: I just noticed you have `z-index` set to 20px which is wrong. There should be a number which represent a position in the element stack.